# How to save multiple files at once through delphi save dialog

Tags: delphi, dialog, save

I'm not able to save multiple files at a time in delphi save dialog box. Multiple files means I want save files without mentioning anything(or only asterisk) at "filename" field in delphi TsaveDialog. Please let me know how to achieve that.

Answer (score 4):

Of course not, because that is not what it is intended for.  You CANNOT obtain *multiple* filenames from a single save dialog.  It only provides *one* filename at a time.  That is by design.

I suspect what you really want is to prompt the user for just a folder path instead. Use the `SelectDirectory()` function (or the Win32 `SHBrowseForFolder()` function directly) for that, then you can create whatever files you need in that folder.

Comment: You have baten me by a few minutes. I suggest that you athleast edit your answer by providing reference to the SelectDirectory documentation (http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.FileCtrl.SelectDirectory) so the OP can chose which of the two posible ways to use it suits him best.

Comment: Yaa, I agree with you. One last question can we customize that save dialog so that it allow us to save multiple files at a time by any chance?

Comment: Modiffy which save dialog? If you mean the default save dialog than I don't think it is possible.

Comment: @Ashis You keep asking the same question. You'd do better explaining why you ask and giving a concrete example.

Answer (score 1):

The save dialog doesn't save files. It allows the user to select file names. The save dialog doesn't support multiple selection so if you want to have a file dialog that allows multiple selections you need an open dialog. But an open dialog typically is used to select names of existing files, whereas a save dialog can specify a name of a file that does not yet exist.

Wildcards when entered into file dialogs are used to filter the displayed list of files. The file dialog won't return file names containing wildcards.

You imagine using wildcards, but how would you be able to do that and create new files? Wildcards are used to pattern match against existing files.

Maybe what you need is a folder selection dialog. Or perhaps you should ask the user for the name of the "master" file and then you generate the names of the "auxiliary" files using the master file name as a stem. I'm guessing because you've not told us any specifics behind your question.

My advice is to reconsider carefully what you are attempting to achieve. Think of all possible corner cases. Explore what UI idioms are used by other programs. Make sure you understand fully the capability of the file dialog controls. And then design your UI to fit with all of these constraints.